# class attribute update into another attribute (list of attribute)

Tags: python

I wonder, how could I pass by reference the four values into the array? It seems that they are passed by value. Here's the minimal reproducing example:

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.q = [self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z]

    def __mul__(self, other):
        q0, q1, q2, q3 = other
        self.w *= q0
        self.x *= q1
        self.y *= q2
        self.z *= q3


test = SomeObject(1, 1, 1, 1)
print(test.q)
>> [1, 1, 1, 1]
test * (2, 2, 2, 2)
print(test.q)
>> [1, 1, 1, 1]
print(test.w)
>> 2
```

Edit: I could use get/set decorators but that's pretty wordy.

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason why this is a bad idea—and while the outcome is the same as what you're going for, it doesn't accomplish pass-by-reference—you could call `__init__` from within `__mul__` to set the new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, all parameters are passed by reference.  However, that doesn't quite mean the same thing as it does in a language like C++.  For example, certain built-in types, such as `int`, are immutable.  Let me give an example.

```py
x = 5
```

Right now, `x` is a reference to an object.  That object is an `int` and holds the value 5.  However, since `int`s are immutable,

```py
x += 1
```

doesn't change the object to which `x` refers from a 5 to a 6.  Instead, `x` is changed to refer to a new object which holds the value 6.

So, when, in `__mul__`, you do `self.w *= q0`, that doesn't change the underlying `int` that `self.w` and `self.q[0]` used to refer to.  `self.w` now refers to a different `int` and `self.q[0]` remains unchanged.

In addition to the mutable/immutable distinction, there's another way in which Python references differ from, say, C++ references.  Reassignment, depending on how it's done, can change the referent object.  For example,

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x # x and y now refer to the same object
y.append(4)
print(x) # [1, 2, 3, 4], because x is y
x = [5, 6, 7] # x now refers to a new object
print(y) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

With in-place arithmetic reassignment, such as `+=`, it goes back to the mutable/immutable issue.  For example, since `int`s are immutable, they can't be changed in place and so the referent has to change.  However, for `list`s,

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x += [4]
print(y) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is because `list`s have an `__iadd__` method which alters the `list` in place.

For something to chew on, consider these examples:

```py
def add_one(x):
    x += 1

def append_one(x):
    x.append(1)

def add_one_list(x):
    x += [1]

def add_one_list_part_2(x):
    x = x + [1]

x = 5
add_one(x)
print(x) # What will be printed?

y = [4, 3, 2]
append_one(y)
add_one_list(y)
add_one_list_part_2(y)
print(y) # What will be printed?
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, cleared the confusion. I indeed had the impression it worked as C++. So the easy fix is to refer to object instead. I find it counter intuitive to treat immutable object differently (both object should still hold the same reference no matter what).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, it's idiomatic to use the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator to create a read-only attribute, like this:

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
        self.w = w
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __mul__(self, other):
        q0, q1, q2, q3 = other
        self.w *= q0
        self.x *= q1
        self.y *= q2
        self.z *= q3

    @property
    def q(self):
        return [self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z]



>>> test = SomeObject(1, 1, 1, 1)
>>> test.q
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> test * (2, 2, 2, 2)
>>> test.q
[2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> test.w
2
```

You still cannot modify w/x/y/z via `q` here, e.g.

```
>>> test.q[0] = 7
>>> test.q
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

but it'd be much more clear to write this as:

```
>>> test.w = 7
>>> test.q
[7, 2, 2, 2]
```

since referencing the 0th index means you know which underlying value you want to change anyhow. ([Explicit better than implicit](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) and all that good stuff.)